# How to convert const char& to const std::string&?

Tags: c++

`std::stof()` needs:

```
float std::stof(const std::wstring &,size_t *)
float std::stof(const std::string &,size_t *)
```

This function is to convert a string, which is delimited by whitespaces, into a vector containing floats. I try to use the `std::stof()` function to convert the characters into floats. I cannot find a solution to convert the `const char&` to the `const std::string&` that `std::stof()` needs.

How do I convert the `const char& s` variable to a `const std::string&` variable?

```
#include<string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<float> parseLine(std::string line)
{
    std::vector<float> parsedLine{};
    for (int i{}; i < line.size(); i++)
    {
            if (line[i] != ' ')
            {
                const char& s = line[i];
                float fs = std::stof(s);
                parsedLine.push_back(fs);
            }

    }
    return parsedLine;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to call a function that needs a whole string with a single character.  Never going to work.

Comment: You can do that like `float fs = std::stof(std::string(1, s));`, but this may not what you want to do. Consider using [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) for parsing lines.

Comment: Okay thank you for the feedback, I'll look into std::stringstream. I am new to the language so I apologize if this was too basic of a question.

Comment: @noobquestionsonly [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should actually search for the whitespace separators and extract substrings between them accordingly, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>

std::vector<float> parseLine(const std::string &line)
{
    auto is_space = [](unsigned char ch){ return std::isspace(ch); };
    std::vector<float> parsedLine;
    auto end = line.begin(), start;
    while ((start = std::find_if_not(end, line.end(), is_space)) != line.end())
    {
        end = std::find_if(start, line.end(), is_space);
        std::string s(start, end);
        float fs = std::stof(s);
        parsedLine.push_back(fs);
    }
    return parsedLine;
}
```

Which can be greatly simplified if you use `std::istringstream` instead:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<float> parseLine(const std::string &line)
{
    std::vector<float> parsedLine;
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    // optional:
    // iss.exceptions(std::istringstream::failbit);
    float fs;
    while (iss >> fs){
        parsedLine.push_back(fs);
    }
    return parsedLine;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [a constructor of `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)

```
basic_string( size_type count,
              CharT ch,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

To convert a character to `std::string`. The reference is `const`, so creating temporal object will work.

```
float fs = std::stof(std::string(1, s));
```

Comment: Yes this will probably fix the compile error, but I doubt the program will deliver the expected results.  There's more than one problem with that code.